# How do I change the contents of a source file for Ifstream every time it loops

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I am writing a program that reads an ifstream file that checks for vowels, consonants, and space; and at the end of the program there is a question that asks the user if they want to run the program again. I want the program to change the content of the ifstream file every time when the user enters Y to restart the program. It seems that the output of the program isn't changed when I change the content of the ifstream.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
ifstream inputFile;
ofstream outputFile;

inputFile.open("data.txt");

if(inputFile.fail()){
    cout << "the file does not work \n";
    exit(1);
}
int vowels = 0,space = 0, consonate =0;

char line;
char redo;
while(inputFile.get(line)){
    
    if(line=='a' || line=='e' || line=='i' ||
       line=='o' || line=='u' || line=='A' ||
       line=='E' || line=='I' || line=='O' ||
       line=='U'){
        vowels++;
    }
    if(line == 'b' || line == 'B' || line == 'c' || line == 'C' || line == 'd' || line == 'D' || line == 'f' || line == 'F' || line == 'g' || line == 'G' || line == 'h' || line == 'H' || line == 'j' || line == 'J' || line == 'k' || line == 'K' || line == 'l' || line == 'L' || line == 'm' || line == 'M' || line == 'n' || line == 'N' || line == 'p' || line == 'P' || line == 'q' || line == 'Q' || line == 'r' || line == 'R' || line == 's' || line == 'S' || line == 't' || line == 'T' || line == 'v' || line == 'V' || line == 'w' || line == 'W' || line == 'x' || line == 'X' || line == 'y' || line == 'Y' || line == 'z' || line == 'Z'){
        consonate++;
    }
    if(line == ' '){
        space++;
    }
   
}
cout << "Vowels = " << vowels << "\n";
cout << "Cosonates = " << consonate << "\n";
cout << "Space = " << space << "\n";
cout << "Would you like to test another file (Y or N): ";
cin >> redo;
switch(redo){
    case 'Y':
    case 'y':
        cout << "You chose to restart the program: ";
        main();
        break;
    case 'N':
    case 'n':
        cout << "You chose to end the program: ";
        inputFile.close();
        break;
        
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: recursively calling main is UB

Comment: How will you program change the text file for the next run if the user answers "y"? You have to install a method to do this, e.g. a random generate characters?

Comment: Or, you may prepare many files, and open a new file for every new run. You have to determine your method first, then the code may help to realize your idea.

Comment: Move all the code that reads the file and parses its contents into its own function. That function should take one argument, the name of the file. It should start by creating an `std::ifstream` object to read from that file, and then loop through the file's contents. In `main` write the code that prompts for input and calls the function.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and then overwriting the default values. In this case, that means changing `ifstream inputFile; ... inputFile.open("data.txt");` to `ifstream inputFile("data.txt");`. And you don't need to call `inputFile.close()`. The destructor will do that.